# Delay the presentation of UIAlertView until its associated viewController is displayed

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a download running in background. It shows an UIAlertView under some fail condition.

When this alert happens, the application can be in any of the views it shows to the user, but only should be visible in one of them.

Can I delay the presentation of the UIAlertView to the moment the viewController it is associated with is displayed to the user (it's viewDidAppear method is invoked)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a property on the view controller that you want to show the view.

```
@interface DownloadViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIAlertView *downloadAlertView;
}

@property (retain) UIAlertView *downloadAlertView;

@end
```

Then, when you detect the error, set the downloadAlertView property of the view controller (this will require you keeping a reference to this view controller by the object that is doing the downloading).

```
- (void)downloadFailed
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] autorelease];
    alertView.title = @"Download Failed";
    downloadViewController.downloadAlertView = alertView;
}
```

Then in your `DownloadViewController` implementation,

```
- (UIAlertView *)downloadAlertView
{
    return downloadAlertView;
}

- (void)setDownloadAlertView:(UIAlertView *)aDownloadAlertView
{
    // standard setter
    [aDownloadAlertView retain];
    [downloadAlertView release];

    downloadAlertView = aDownloadAlertView;

    // show the alert view if this view controller is currently visible
    if (viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window) 
    {
         [downloadAlertView show];
         downloadAlertView = nil;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    if (downloadAlertView)
    {
        [downloadAlertView show];
        downloadAlertView = nil;
    }
}
```

Quick explanation:

- the first two methods are standard getter/setters, but the setter has added logic, so that if the view controller is currently visible, the alert is shown immediately.
- if not, the alert view is stored by the view controller and shown as soon as the view appears.

Comment: Nice approach. I'm on it, but could you explain the `(viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window)` conditional?, is it the same as `(self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self)`?

Comment: Shouldn`t you reference in code downloadAlertView as self.downloadAlertView?

Comment: Check the name of the setter, should be setDownloadAlertView.

Comment: @DavidCasillas the `(viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window)` line would be equivalent to `self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self`, but would also work if the view controller was being displayed modally or in a UITabBarController. In the class, it's ok to use the the instance variable directly, since you know the getter implementation just returns this anyway. Some might consider this bad style, but I don't see a problem... And thanks for the heads up on the setter!